# Ionic 2 Page Unresponsive

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

Find below a page in Ionic 2 that pulls data from a service and immediately becomes unresonsive, I can not click on anything both on a device, simulator even on browser.

home.html

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar hideBackButton="true" danger>
    <button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>Shoppa</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content class="cards-bg social-cards">

  <ion-card *ngFor="let campaign of campaigns">

    <ion-item>
      <ion-avatar item-left>
        <img [src]="campaign.image">
      </ion-avatar>
      <h2>{{campaign.name}}</h2>
      <p>July 5, 2016</p>
    </ion-item>

    <img [src]="campaign.image">

    <ion-card-content>
      <p>{{campaign.description}}</p>
    </ion-card-content>

    <ion-row>
      <ion-col>
        <button primary clear small (click)="likeCampaign(campaign)" disabled= {{buttonDisabled}}>
          <ion-icon name='thumbs-up'></ion-icon>
          <div>{{campaign.likes.length}} Likes</div>
        </button>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        <button primary clear small (click)="shareCampaign(campaign)">
          <ion-icon ios="ios-share" md="md-share"></ion-icon>
          <div>{{campaign.share.length}} Shares</div>
        </button>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        <button primary clear small (click)="optInToCampaign(campaign)">
          <ion-icon name='person-add'></ion-icon>
          <div>{{campaign.wantin.length}} Opt In</div>
        </button>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>

  </ion-card>

</ion-content>

<style>
  .social-cards ion-col {
    padding: 0;
  }
</style>
```

home.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Toast, SocialSharing } from 'ionic-native';

import { CampaignProvider } from '../../providers/campaign-provider/campaign-provider';
import { UserProvider } from '../../providers/user-provider/user-provider';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/home/home.html',
  providers: [CampaignProvider]
})

export class HomePage {
  campaignOject: {name?:string, image?:string, description?: string, likes?: number, shares?:number, wantin?:number } = {};
  campaigns = [];
  like:{email?:string, campaignid?:string} ={};
  buttonDisabled:boolean;
  user:{email?: string} = {};

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private campaignProvider: CampaignProvider, private userProvider: UserProvider) {
    this.buttonDisabled = null;

    this.user.email = userProvider.GetLocalObject("user");
    this.getCampaigns();
  }

  ionViewWillEnter(){
    console.log('Entered into the view');
  }

  ionViewDidEnter(){
    console.log('Page was fully loaded');
  }

  getCampaigns(){
    console.log(this.user);

    this.campaignProvider.GetUserCampaigns(this.user).subscribe(
        data => {
        console.log(data.result);
        console.log(data.message);
        this.campaigns = data.result;
      },
        err => {
        console.log(err);
      },
      () => console.log('Pulling data')
    )
  }

  likeCampaign(campaign){
    console.log(campaign.name + ' has been liked');


    this.like.email = 'kolexinfos@gmail.com';
    this.like.campaignid = campaign._id;
    //TODO: Pick the User Email from localstorage
    //campaign.email = 'kolexinfos@gmail.com';

    console.log(this.like);
    this.campaignProvider.LikeCampaigns(this.like).subscribe(
      data => {
        console.log(data.result);
        this.buttonDisabled = true;
        Toast.show(campaign.name + " liked", "short", 'bottom').subscribe(
            toast => {
            console.log(toast);
          }
        );

      },
      err => {
        console.log(err);
      },
      () => console.log(campaign.name + ' campaign was liked.')
    )
    this.getCampaigns();
  }

  optInToCampaign(campaign){
    console.log(campaign.name + ' has been opted into' );

    this.like.email = 'kolexinfos@gmail.com';
    this.like.campaignid = campaign._id;
    //TODO: Pick the User Email from localstorage

    this.campaignProvider.WantInCampaign(this.like).subscribe(
        data => {
        console.log(data.result);
          Toast.show(campaign.name + " opted in to", "short", 'bottom').subscribe(
              toast => {
              console.log(toast);
            }
          );
      },
        err => {
        console.log(err);
      },
      () => console.log(campaign.name + ' campaign was liked.')
    )

    this.getCampaigns();
  }

  shareCampaign(campaign){
    console.log(campaign.name + ' has been shared');

    this.like.email = 'kolexinfos@gmail.com';
    this.like.campaignid = campaign._id;
    //TODO: Pick the User Email from localstorage

    SocialSharing.share(campaign.description, campaign.name,campaign.image).then(() =>{
      console.log("Success");

        this.campaignProvider.ShareCampaign(campaign).subscribe(
            data => {
            console.log(data.result);
              Toast.show(campaign.name + " shared", "short", 'bottom').subscribe(
                  toast => {
                  console.log(toast);
                }
              );
          },
            err => {
            console.log(err);
          },
          () => console.log(campaign.name + ' campaign was shared.')
        )

    }).catch(() => {
      console.log("Error");
    });

    this.getCampaigns();
  }

}
```

Console Log

```
Angular 2 is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
Native: tried calling StatusBar.styleDefault, but Cordova is not available. Make sure to include cordova.js or run in a device/simulator
Native: tried calling Splashscreen.hide, but Cordova is not available. Make sure to include cordova.js or run in a device/simulator
WARNING: sanitizing HTML stripped some content (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss).
WARNING: sanitizing HTML stripped some content (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss).
WARNING: sanitizing HTML stripped some content (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss).
ionViewWillEnter called
kolexinfos@mail.com
swiper initEvents attach
Object {email: "kolexinfos@mail.com"}
Username for user [object Object]
Entered into the view
Object {email: "kolexinfos@mail.com"}
Username for user [object Object]
Entered into the view
Page was fully loaded
[Object, Object, Object]
Successfully pulled the Campaigns 
Pulling data
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://ide.c9.io/kolexinfos/shoppa' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://preptitude.com.ng/shoppa/shoprite.jpg'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://ide.c9.io/kolexinfos/shoppa' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://preptitude.com.ng/shoppa/shoprite.jpg'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://ide.c9.io/kolexinfos/shoppa' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://preptitude.com.ng/shoppa/deola.jpg'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://ide.c9.io/kolexinfos/shoppa' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://preptitude.com.ng/shoppa/nike.jpg'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.
[Object, Object, Object]
Successfully pulled the Campaigns 
Pulling data
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://ide.c9.io/kolexinfos/shoppa' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://preptitude.com.ng/shoppa/shoprite.jpg'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://ide.c9.io/kolexinfos/shoppa' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://preptitude.com.ng/shoppa/shoprite.jpg'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://ide.c9.io/kolexinfos/shoppa' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://preptitude.com.ng/shoppa/deola.jpg'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://ide.c9.io/kolexinfos/shoppa' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://preptitude.com.ng/shoppa/deola.jpg'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://ide.c9.io/kolexinfos/shoppa' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://preptitude.com.ng/shoppa/nike.jpg'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://ide.c9.io/kolexinfos/shoppa' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://preptitude.com.ng/shoppa/nike.jpg'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.
```

Comment: Can you post the entire `home.ts` code?

Comment: @sebaferreras done check edits

Comment: Can you post the logs from the console.

Comment: @prerak Done find edits

Comment: can you post the service code also

Comment: This is a bug in ionic as stated here https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/8453. When I navigate to the page with nav.push the whole scrolling starts working(but no menu) but setRoot blocks the whole UI from user intertaction

Answer (score 0):

I would try calling `this.getCampaigns();` inside an `ionViewDidLoad(){}`. This should ensure that all providers are instantiated before trying to access them.

Another issue that can come up due to the asynchronous nature of such scenarios would be if the value is emitted *before* the subscription has taken place. In some previous such scenarios of mine I would subscribe inside an `ngOnInit(){}`. This a [lifecycle hook of Angular](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html) and I'm not exactly sure what the [equivalent hook is for Ionic](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/).